# How to animate changes to a Path driven by changes to model in SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui

How to animate changes to a path driven by changes to model

I am teaching myself SwiftUI. I have a UIKIt demo app, [**RoundedCornerPolygon**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/RoundedCornerPolygon.git), on Github, which allows you to create n-sided polygons with any mixture of sharp and rounded corners.

The UI in the demo app builds a square with switches to control the rounding of each of the 4 corners. It animates changes. It's animation looks like this:

[image]

(The underlying code can generate convex or concave polygons with any number of vertexes.)

I’d like to convert that project to SwiftUI as an exercise. The code that generates the polygon paths will be directly useable, since it creates `CGPath`s, and there is an initializer for SwiftUI’s `Path` that takes a `CGPath`.

My RoundedCornerPolygon project builds it’s path from an array of `PolygonPoint` structs named **points**, where a `PolygonPoint` looks like this:

```
/// A struct describing a single vertex in a polygon. Used in building polygon paths with a mixture of rounded an sharp-edged vertexes.
public struct PolygonPoint {
    let point: CGPoint
    let isRounded: Bool
    let customCornerRadius: CGFloat?
    init(point: CGPoint,
         isRounded: Bool,
         customCornerRadius: CGFloat? = nil) {
        self.point = point
        self.isRounded = isRounded
        self.customCornerRadius = customCornerRadius
    }

    init(previousPoint: PolygonPoint, isRounded: Bool) {
        self.init(point: previousPoint.point, isRounded: isRounded, customCornerRadius: previousPoint.customCornerRadius)
    }
}
```

My goal is to have the SwiftUI program treat the array of `PolygonPoint`s as a `@state` or `@ObservedObject`, and have changes to the **points** `PolygonPoint` array cause my polygon view to animate a change to it’s path. I’m learning about `animatableData` as a way of driving animations, but I don’t know how to trigger animations based on a complex model object like my array of `PolygonPoint`s.

**The question**: How should I set up my SwiftUI model so that changes to to my array of `PolygonPoint`s trigger rebuilding the Path object with a new CGPath and animating that updated Path?

I've tried a simple project where it used a struct as `animatableData`, but the changes don't animate in that case.

My initial experiment was to modify some sample code I found here on SO in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64446507/205185). That answer sets up a `CGFloat` variable `offset` as animatableData. I tried refactoring it to instead define an `ArrowData` struct containing both the width and offset for the arrow, and make my `ArrowData` struct the MyArrow `Shape`'s `animatableData`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ArrowData: Hashable {
  var width: CGFloat
  var offset: CGFloat
}

struct MyArrow: Shape {
  
  var arrowData: ArrowData
    
    var animatableData: ArrowData {
        get { arrowData }
      set {
        print("ArrowData changed")
        arrowData = newValue
      }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: .zero)
          path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: arrowData.width/2, y: arrowData.offset))
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: arrowData.width/2, y: arrowData.offset))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: arrowData.width, y: 0))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var change = false
    
    private let arrowWidth: CGFloat = 60
    
    
    var body: some View {
      MyArrow(arrowData: ArrowData(width: arrowWidth, offset: change ? -20 : 20))
        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 12, lineCap: .round))
        .frame(width: arrowWidth)
        .foregroundColor(.green)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture { withAnimation { change.toggle() } }
        .onTapGesture { change.toggle() }
        .padding(.top, 300)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

After those changes the arrow still redraws when you change the ArrowData, but it no longer animates. The SwiftUI version looks like this:

[image: SwiftUI version]

---

## Edit:

My attempt:

---

Ok, after looking at lorem ipsum's answer, I took a stab at writing a SwiftUI version of my RoundedCornerPolygon project, and it still doesn't work. You can download the project from Github at https://github.com/DuncanMC/RoundedCornerPolygonSwiftUI.git.

What I did:

I made my `PolygonPoint` struct conform to `Hashable` and `VectorArithmetic`.

```
/// A struct describing a single vertex in a polygon. Used in building polygon paths with a mixture of rounded an sharp-edged vertexes.
public struct PolygonPoint: Hashable, VectorArithmetic {
    var point: CGPoint
    var isRounded: Bool
    var customCornerRadius: CGFloat?
    
    init(point: CGPoint,
         isRounded: Bool,
         customCornerRadius: CGFloat? = nil) {
        self.point = point
        self.isRounded = isRounded
        self.customCornerRadius = customCornerRadius
    }
    init(previousPoint: PolygonPoint, isRounded: Bool) {
        self.init(point: previousPoint.point, isRounded: isRounded, customCornerRadius: previousPoint.customCornerRadius)
    }
    //MARK: VectorArithmetic
    public var magnitudeSquared: Double = 1
    
    public static var zero: PolygonPoint = .init(point: .zero, isRounded: false, customCornerRadius: .zero)
    
    public mutating func scale(by rhs: Double) {
        self = .init(point: point * rhs,
                     isRounded:
                        self.isRounded,
                     customCornerRadius:
                        self.customCornerRadius
        )
    }
    public static func + (lhs: PolygonPoint, rhs: PolygonPoint) -> PolygonPoint {
        
        .init(point: lhs.point + rhs.point,
              isRounded:
                lhs.isRounded && rhs.isRounded,
              customCornerRadius:
                // Which point's corner radius should it use?
                max(lhs.customCornerRadius ?? 0, rhs.customCornerRadius ?? 0)
        )
    }
    public static func - (lhs: PolygonPoint, rhs: PolygonPoint) -> PolygonPoint {
        
        .init(point: lhs.point - rhs.point,
              isRounded:
                lhs.isRounded || rhs.isRounded,
              customCornerRadius:
                max(lhs.customCornerRadius ?? 0, rhs.customCornerRadius ?? 0)
        )
    }
}
```

I created a `PolygonShape` `View` that manages a `Path` and uses an array of `PolygonPoint`s as animatableData. **In theory**, changes to the array of `PolygonPoint`s should animate:

```
struct PolygonShape: View {
  
  var defaultCornerRadius: CGFloat
  var controlPoints: [PolygonPoint]
  
  var animatableData: [PolygonPoint] {
    get { controlPoints}
    set { controlPoints = newValue}
  }

  var body: some View {
    Path(buildPolygonPathFrom(points: controlPoints, defaultCornerRadius: defaultCornerRadius))
      .stroke()
  }
}
```

I gave the app's ContentView a `@State` variable containing the array of`PolygonPoint`s that builds my path.

The ContentView also uses a ForEach loop to build a Stack of Toggles from the `@State` array of `ControlPoint` objects. When you change the state of the Toggle, the binding changes the value in the associated `ControlPoint`. That causes the ContentView to rebuild the `PolygonShape` with a new array of `ControlPoint`s:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 30
  @State var controlPoints: [PolygonPoint]
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      PolygonShape(defaultCornerRadius: cornerRadius,
                   controlPoints: controlPoints)
      Spacer()
        .frame(width: 0, height: 20)
      VStack(alignment: .center) {
        ForEach(Array(controlPoints.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, point in
          HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Spacer()
              .frame(width: 50)
            Toggle("Round corner \(index)", isOn: self.$controlPoints[index].isRounded)
            Spacer()
              .frame(width: 50)
          }
        }
      }
      Spacer()
        .frame(minHeight: 50)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add an animation to the struct you tried?

Comment: How would I "add animation to the struct?"

Comment: Not the `struct` the `Shape` when the `offset` changes animate. something like `.animation(.linear, value: change)` applied to `MyArrow`

Comment: @loremipsum I am using that project as a way to figure out how to animate changes to a more complex model object rather than just the offset value.

Answer (score 0):

I just took at look at your code and notice that you are missing the "magic" behind `Animatable`.

SwiftUI uses `Hashable` to manage identity and it uses `VectorArithmetic` to do the math for `Animatable` so `ArrowData` has to use `some VectorArithmetic`

An easy solution would be to use `AnimatablePair<CGFloat, CGFloat>` instead of `var animatableData: ArrowData`

```
struct MyArrow: Shape {
    
    var arrowData: ArrowData
    
    var animatableData: AnimatablePair<CGFloat, CGFloat> {
        get {
            .init(arrowData.width, arrowData.offset)
        }
        set {
            arrowData = .init(width: newValue.first, offset: newValue.second)
        }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: .zero)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: arrowData.width/2, y: arrowData.offset))
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: arrowData.width/2, y: arrowData.offset))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: arrowData.width, y: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

But a more scalable solution is to make `ArrowData` conform.

```
struct ArrowData: Hashable, VectorArithmetic
```

It doesn't take much.

```
struct ArrowData: Hashable, VectorArithmetic {
    
    var width: CGFloat
    var offset: CGFloat
    //MARK: VectorArithmetic
    var magnitudeSquared: Double = 1
    
    static var zero: ArrowData = ArrowData(width: .zero, offset: .zero)
    
    mutating func scale(by rhs: Double) {
        width = width * rhs
        offset = offset * rhs
    }
    static func - (lhs: ArrowData, rhs: ArrowData) -> ArrowData {
        .init(width: lhs.width - rhs.width, offset: lhs.offset - rhs.offset)
        
    }
    
    static func + (lhs: ArrowData, rhs: ArrowData) -> ArrowData {
        .init(width: lhs.width + rhs.width, offset: lhs.offset + rhs.offset)
    }
}
```

Then you can use it directly.

```
struct MyArrow: Shape {
    
    var arrowData: ArrowData

    var animatableData: ArrowData {
        get {
            arrowData
        }
        set {
            arrowData = newValue
        }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: .zero)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: arrowData.width/2, y: arrowData.offset))
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: arrowData.width/2, y: arrowData.offset))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: arrowData.width, y: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

You can make your `PolygonPoint` conform cleanly too with some `extension`s.

```
public struct PolygonPoint: Hashable, VectorArithmetic {
    let point: CGPoint
    let isRounded: Bool
    let customCornerRadius: CGFloat?
    
    init(point: CGPoint,
         isRounded: Bool,
         customCornerRadius: CGFloat? = nil) {
        self.point = point
        self.isRounded = isRounded
        self.customCornerRadius = customCornerRadius
    }
    init(previousPoint: PolygonPoint, isRounded: Bool) {
        self.init(point: previousPoint.point, isRounded: isRounded, customCornerRadius: previousPoint.customCornerRadius)
    }
    //MARK: VectorArithmetic
    public var magnitudeSquared: Double = 1
    
    public static var zero: PolygonPoint = .init(point: .zero, isRounded: false, customCornerRadius: .zero)
    
    public mutating func scale(by rhs: Double) {
        self = .init(point: point * rhs,
                     isRounded:
                        self.isRounded,
                     customCornerRadius:
                        self.customCornerRadius * rhs
        )
    }
    public static func + (lhs: PolygonPoint, rhs: PolygonPoint) -> PolygonPoint {
        
        .init(point: lhs.point + rhs.point,
              isRounded:
                lhs.isRounded && rhs.isRounded,
              customCornerRadius:
                lhs.customCornerRadius + rhs.customCornerRadius
        )
    }
    public static func - (lhs: PolygonPoint, rhs: PolygonPoint) -> PolygonPoint {
        
        .init(point: lhs.point - rhs.point,
              isRounded:
                lhs.isRounded || rhs.isRounded,
              customCornerRadius:
                lhs.customCornerRadius - rhs.customCornerRadius
        )
    }
}

extension CGPoint: AdditiveArithmetic  {
    public static func + (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: lhs.x + rhs.x, y: lhs.y + rhs.y)
    }
    public static func * (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: lhs.x * rhs.x, y: lhs.y * rhs.y)
    }
    public static func * (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: Double) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: lhs.x * rhs, y: lhs.y * rhs)
    }
    public static func - (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: lhs.x - rhs.x, y: lhs.y - rhs.y)
    }
}
extension CGFloat? {
    public static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        if let lhs, let rhs {
            return lhs + rhs
        } else if let lhs {
            return lhs
        } else if let rhs {
            return rhs
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    public static func - (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        if let lhs, let rhs {
            return lhs - rhs
        } else if let lhs {
            return lhs
        } else if let rhs {
            return rhs
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    public static func * (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        if let lhs, let rhs {
            return lhs * rhs
        } else if let lhs {
            return lhs
        } else if let rhs {
            return rhs
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    public static func * (lhs: Self, rhs: Double) -> Self {
        if let lhs {
            return lhs * rhs
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
extension CGPoint: Hashable {
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(x)
        hasher.combine(y)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, for the very simple Arrow project, making the `ArrowData` conform to VectorArithmetic is pretty simple. What about for my goal, which is to animate a path generated from an array of `PolygonPoint` structs, which cleanly conform to `VectorArithmetic`?

Comment: @DuncanC same premise, just make it conform and use extensions when you want to clean and reuse code.

Comment: @DuncanC I added some code above, handling `Bool` likely needs revising, you might want to adopt `rhs`'s value instead of `&&` or `||`

Comment: And what about making my `animatableData` an array of `PolygonPoint`s?

Comment: @DuncanC you would just have to add another extension that handles the math. There would be a ton of decisions to make but shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but it doesn't work. See the repo at https://github.com/DuncanMC/RoundedCornerPolygonSwiftUI.git. I'll update my question with the latest code and what it does. tl;dr: The goal is to animate the corners moving between rounded and non-rounded, and that doesn't work.

Comment: @DuncanC SwiftUI only works smoothly if it can preserve identity, `enumerated` breaks that, I see if I can dedicate some time to the code added to the question later if there is no way to follow SwiftUI rules in the `ForEach` it will never work. `index` is unsafe with SwiftUI. It shouldn't be used.

Comment: @DuncanC you also likely need to make an array extension conform

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @DuncanC Same way I wrote the other code, Ive never made an array conform to VA but it shouldn't be much different.

Comment: I have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: @DuncanC lol someone with 100k+ points has no idea how to write an extension? already answered your question of how to animate changes to a model and you keep adding to the question. You know the rules about an MRE I have no plans on getting code from your git, I don't do that on SO. I am usually not picky about writing code I like solving stuff but saying you have no idea how to write an extension seems a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I know full well how to write an extension. I have no idea how to write an extension that makes an array conform to VectorArithmetic.

Comment: @DuncanC Ive never written one either but just for fun I just did and I dont think it is possible without breaking identity. It just jumps to the new position the `+` and `-` run as expected  but values are not incremental for the points.

Comment: What I really want is what I can do from Core Animation: Update a path with a new path and have the changes animate. Not strokeBegin or StrokeEnd, but a different path.

Comment: @DuncanC that should be much more manageable. A struct with a path and a shape, 1 to 1 not 1 shape to many items.